# Некоректный вывод в цикле

Tags: python, python-3.x, for

Задача: Добавлять из всех спаршенных комментариев по одному в список comments.

Проблема: Добавляются по одной букве из комментария (Пример: ['B', 'o', 'n', 'e', 's', 'a', 'n', 'd', ' ', 'x', 'T', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'o', 'n', 'e', 's', ' ', 'f', 'o', 'r'])

```
comments = []
comment_current = -1
while comment_current >= -30:
    for comment in response_comms['items'][comment_current]['snippet']['displayMessage']:
        comments.append(comment)
        print(comment)
    comment_current -= 1
```

Comment: Очевидно, по ключу `'displayMessage'` у Вас находится строка и Вы итерируетесь по каждой её букве.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов В точку! А как мне итерировать по самому комментарию??

Comment: То есть добавлять целый комментарий

Comment: Добавлять diaplamessage целиком, без всяких циклов.

Comment: @Эникейщик Да, действительно помогло!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
comments = []
comment_current = -1
while comment_current >= -30:
        comments.append(comment)
        print(comment)
    comment_current -= 1
```